# Dataframe Column into Multiple Columns by delimiter ',' : expand = True, n =-1

Tags: pandas, split, multiple-columns

My first question thanks) Sorry for lengthy formulationenter image description here
Researched all related posts

**What I have**

- my Dataframe column (please see screenshot) is strings separated by delimiter ',' Car parameters.

**My Dataframe:-**

[image]

- Some  rows come with mileage while others not (screenshot) hence some rows have fewer delimiters.

**The Task**

- Need to create 5 columns (max number of delimiters) to store CarParameters separately (Mileage, GearBox, HP, Body etc)
- If a row doesn't have Mileage Put 0 in the Mileage Column

**What I know and works well**

`df["name"].str.split(" ", expand = True)` by default `n=-1` and splits into necessary columns
example:

**The issue:**

- If I use the `str.split(" ", expand = True)` method - GearBox (ATM) is wrongly put under newly created Mileage column because that row is short of one delimiter (screenshot)

Result:-

[image]

-

Comment: can you provide the first 10 rows of your dataframe as text? `print(df.head(10).to_dict)` and paste it into your question, see [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: Thank you fair point noted down and will do for future posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try lambda function combined with list concatenation like below.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['1,2,3,4,5'],['2,3,4,5']], columns=["CarParameters"])
>>> print(pd.DataFrame(df.CarParameters.apply(
       lambda x: str(x).split(',')).apply(
          lambda x: [0]*(5-len(x)) + x).to_list(), columns=list("ABCDE")))

   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  0  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: did you test it? it seems that some rows wont be equally sized.

Comment: yes, I have tested it. 
`[0]*(5-len(x)) + x`:  is making all 4 sized rows to 5

Comment: can you post final result?

Comment: I have Added the result in the answer

Comment: WOWWW!!! Thank you So very much. I spent two days really solving for this! Can't thank you enough, worked like a charm